# How to forward traffic from tun0 to specific IP behind eth0 (iptables)

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, vpn, iptables, port-forwarding

My raspberry pi is connected to a OpenVPN server on interface tun0. The internet connection is setup over a 3G/UMTS mobile stick(eth1).

How can I forward all traffic coming from tun0 to a device with a static ip-adress behind eth0(ethernet port) with iptables?

I added this rule to allow forwarding:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

But how can I route all traffic on a specific ip behind eth0?

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while since you have posted this question, but I am trying to do exactly the same thing as you have described here. I am not really good at all this networking shenanigans. Would you be able to post your `/etc/network/interfaces` or point me into some tutorials you have used to configure your Pi? I would greatly appreciate this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use "DNAT" for this. You do DNAT in the PREROUTING nat table.

Probablly something along the lines of

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -j DNAT --to-destination <destination ip>